# SQL - Alternative to WHERE AND/OR clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a beginner and I have basic knowledge on the matter, so i apoligize if i couldn't find the right answer.
Here's the code I've written. It returns exactly what I need but I feel like it's not a great solution, any suggestions?
I'm working on Oracle SQL Developer. Thanks in advance

```
SELECT
    ta.id,
    tb.taid,
    tc.idb,
    ta.durata,
    tc.durata,
    tb.durata,
    ta.data_attivazione,
    ta.data_disattivazione,
    tc.data_inizio,
    tc.data_fine,
    tb.data_inizio,
    tb.data_fine
FROM
    tableA ta
    tableB ta
    tableC tc
WHERE
    ta.id = 3456
    AND tb.taid = 3456
    AND tc.idb = 3456
    OR (
        ta.id = 3457
        AND tb.taid = 3457
        AND tc.idb = 3457
    )
```

Comment: I expect the query to return 2 rows, each with either 3456 or 3457.

Comment: Please stop using implicit joins (comma separated), always use explicit `join` syntax. It's ANSI standard for neigh on 30 years!

Answer (score 4):

Use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax:

```
select . . .
from tableA ta join
     tableB tb
     on ta.id = tb.taid join
     tableC tc
     on tc.idb = ta.id
where ta.id in (3456, 3457)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `join`:

```
SELECT
    ta.id,
    tb.taid,
    tc.idb,
    ta.durata,
    tc.durata,
    tb.durata,
    ta.data_attivazione,
    ta.data_disattivazione,
    tc.data_inizio,
    tc.data_fine,
    tb.data_inizio,
    tb.data_fine
FROM
    tableA ta join tableB tb on ta.id= tb.taid
    join tableC tc on tb.taid = tc.idb
WHERE
    ta.id in (3456, 3457)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the join to simplify your code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6v1w.png)